# Is it possible to get local business results through the Google APIs?

Tags: google-maps

Is it easy to get the business listings such as when you search in Google Maps?

If there is an API that would be great! In any language, preferable, PHP or javascript

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481142.

Answer (score 0):

You can do local search via the Google AJAX search API.

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_class_GlocalSearch