# How to get full detail of address by google map api in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps, google-places

I am trying to get full detail of address by google map api but only getting few. Currently I am using package `composer require lodge/postcode-lookup`  which is used to get address by post code

```
array:9 [▼
  "postcode" => "M5G1M7"
  "street_number" => "641"
  "street" => "Bay Street"
  "sublocality" => "Old Toronto"
  "town" => "Toronto"
  "county" => "Toronto"
  "country" => "Canada"
  "latitude" => 43.6569641
  "longitude" => -79.3839517
]
```

but some detail is missing like this is post code of restaurant . so it should total reviews, week days opening and close timing ... and keywords etc ..

How I can get those details

Comment: I think you are confusing their Maps API for their Places/Business API. The Maps API returns only address related data. You probably want this one https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details

Comment: I think you are mistaken about what the API does. From a quick lookup, and from name, you are searching based on post code. Meaning you are looking up address information based on post code. Also here is another question regarding the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481142/how-do-i-get-local-business-results-using-google-maps-api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get local business results using google maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481142/how-do-i-get-local-business-results-using-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API doesn't return Place related data. This is reserved for the Places API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details

```
{
"html_attributions": [],
  "result":
    {
      "address_components":
        [
          { "long_name": "48", "short_name": "48", "types": ["street_number"] },
          {
            "long_name": "Pirrama Road",
            "short_name": "Pirrama Rd",
            "types": ["route"],
          },
          {
            "long_name": "Pyrmont",
            "short_name": "Pyrmont",
            "types": ["locality", "political"],
          },
          {
            "long_name": "Council of the City of Sydney",
            "short_name": "Sydney",
            "types": ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"],
          },
          {
            "long_name": "New South Wales",
            "short_name": "NSW",
            "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"],
          },
          {
            "long_name": "Australia",
            "short_name": "AU",
            "types": ["country", "political"],
          },
          {
            "long_name": "2009",
            "short_name": "2009",
            "types": ["postal_code"],
          },
        ],
      "adr_address": '<span class="street-address">48 Pirrama Rd</span>, <span class="locality">Pyrmont</span> <span class="region">NSW</span> <span class="postal-code">2009</span>, <span class="country-name">Australia</span>',
      "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
      "formatted_address": "48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont NSW 2009, Australia",
      "formatted_phone_number": "(02) 9374 4000",
      "geometry":
        {
          "location": { "lat": -33.866489, "lng": 151.1958561 },
          "viewport":
            {
              "northeast":
                { "lat": -33.8655112697085, "lng": 151.1971156302915 },
              "southwest":
                { "lat": -33.86820923029149, "lng": 151.1944176697085 },
            },
        },
      "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_business-71.png",
      "icon_background_color": "#7B9EB0",
      "icon_mask_base_uri": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_pinlet",
      "international_phone_number": "+61 2 9374 4000",
      "name": "Google Workplace 6",
      "opening_hours":
        {
          "open_now": false,
          "periods":
            [
              {
                "close": { "day": 1, "time": "1700" },
                "open": { "day": 1, "time": "0900" },
              },
              {
                "close": { "day": 2, "time": "1700" },
                "open": { "day": 2, "time": "0900" },
              },
              {
                "close": { "day": 3, "time": "1700" },
                "open": { "day": 3, "time": "0900" },
              },
              {
                "close": { "day": 4, "time": "1700" },
                "open": { "day": 4, "time": "0900" },
              },
              {
                "close": { "day": 5, "time": "1700" },
                "open": { "day": 5, "time": "0900" },
              },
            ],
          "weekday_text":
            [
              "Monday: 9:00 AM – 5:00 PM",
              "Tuesday: 9:00 AM – 5:00 PM",
              "Wednesday: 9:00 AM – 5:00 PM",
              "Thursday: 9:00 AM – 5:00 PM",
              "Friday: 9:00 AM – 5:00 PM",
              "Saturday: Closed",
              "Sunday: Closed",
            ],
        },
      "photos":
        [
          {
            "height": 3024,
            "html_attributions":
              [
                '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105067373811767106297">Shaun Craig</a>',
              ],
            "photo_reference": "Aap_uECTSiFbO2Qg81vEQkbLMh4wHhilVWH4l3oNCqj2NHeTK0VUey6lTn_jhUfeKUubL8aWmhl_nx3ilV-dZqeIlyaS-q6Oo_UNn-aUjy1JSrKzZxjBwCEp0dZi8WyS_0dooU2C-oR0gZRjNK14dbwqto2E8g2c9upoiJPQTWNoqYtgbdoa",
            "width": 4032,
          },
          {
            "height": 3264,
            "html_attributions":
              [
                '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102493344958625549078">Heyang Li</a>',
              ],
            "photo_reference": "Aap_uEATBbKi76kbA2OColmGnmruSknqNKhf4kMJX_YlCXvQaWJhSqkSdkDxF3hmoyAJk1slQrG8TmZwsO7FkzAQQ0x1tIknYf-v0O01LWIQbva9EyuQUyYXALJNAr7ixCKBMjyKywQqfGZRNVbEfSqIxUrTG4HZDx9VRe1sAMydadUyuUXs",
            "width": 4912,
          },
          {
            "height": 1836,
            "html_attributions":
              [
                '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116807455538142476628">Anand Ema</a>',
              ],
            "photo_reference": "Aap_uECyuzfnLNlfA5ioL01LpmwUfDsjM398AT8Ysd6qrGTwevk1OT44jsw8a0dsNQX8rPA5Pmt6A0mWGh4p2J4e1dFgifnWGN17Pn8QgUmKcGlXUJFZKfqp5hQmfvtjqPBMBtmZ3oMIq8sX1DCHpcVx-DZI3Pt0iXMyFDPmfnrjarPIj9YW",
            "width": 3264,
          },
          {
            "height": 3024,
            "html_attributions":
              [
                '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115886271727815775491">Anthony Huynh</a>',
              ],
            "photo_reference": "Aap_uEDW89cNhv_xXN124XRb451wdOwLJ1LTIuZ-ESOHr3g9NyXqeBLjy4O0xhRP6xCt0pt62aJi7fkCrc_Xy3t-UYU1nSZoOfs9z1fR7ICFTxOBHJzjxQACA45SRu99iSw5bbvFgPODXfViTwNzz81R6rMs39dRqTNmk9sYq5nss_2GOkFm",
            "width": 4032,
          },
          {
            "height": 3024,
            "html_attributions":
              [
                '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102939237947063969663">Jasen Baker</a>',
              ],
            "photo_reference": "Aap_uEBNxWNbur6GObqQuIDMflRwEM79ItI4d3Fpgg_hn5fAljaTu40e47VAaT5TTBVoxRJ2tKIbUhhpUo-VDMxHd2nHE4QtrQntp8x5ddBZudB8Re7xdi3aUaQOGw7SWqFh6WwhRY6gYQ3EYK98pH6VNF5_-Bu005dd0W9ldyyjXBfz4S6T",
            "width": 4032,
          },
          {
            "height": 3024,
            "html_attributions":
              [
                '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100678816592586275978">Jeremy Hsiao</a>',
              ],
            "photo_reference": "Aap_uEAKW4dw7yC3vl6QWIu1vx5hIUHTkjccM4K-za6_zRgwxFzlWxAFJ9M7HlCyMfasQH_fC2c0hY9AZh0z8vZd_pB5xTFDbLZrDq6PayaXME6Y2vgGrSgHOSCtYC2vDODT4Q-_TCBgWfBT0CYfHOE9tMpZWrH1KT6u-Zv3NYBbXa3ssyrk",
            "width": 4032,
          },
          {
            "height": 3024,
            "html_attributions":
              [
                '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100678816592586275978">Jeremy Hsiao</a>',
              ],
            "photo_reference": "Aap_uEACMvdbZdKXZP4E9aOw9eeoBVbKsQh0TcbYzqRiUzZkAx09ykX2r5gf66d5n5KzqmUBGdHavSpHye_-ZKpp2UeMuufmx6vwWx9sQtVXDZ5uI6O0yg29BorK5KHzxWqahAFuJRLHOmaYSwwnno318UrR5alb-zFXqeuNpa95e_sn0YW4",
            "width": 4032,
          },
          {
            "height": 3036,
            "html_attributions":
              [
                '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100482974853389838438">Mark Vozzo</a>',
              ],
            "photo_reference": "Aap_uEBE3MuFrsb-nu8po-FsX1zvFatDzSzY1asoBtu6EAQbcukr843rJm7gpI8loe0c_WBAUv4XmnWwhj4U0HHx8Ka5WAKgQBUZGI-XMO1UP44bwMo0Q5XqjyfWwsIgzBJbYftFY-YA_7FEVPMHqgIHkK_weWkW7Gn95gILlM1En0LJUJH6",
            "width": 4048,
          },
          {
            "height": 498,
            "html_attributions":
              [
                '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/103245129386449712319">Simon TestOne</a>',
              ],
            "photo_reference": "Aap_uEBe5dY4U34xvY4zH0xCl2pAXyJI3IDrVs8AJFZG9sC7qcGeZ_T56RwJ8avcGJI7iT7WvRytV1vMOFaQfTUx5R8fWZwPaHBqqKSskEDJ7zZKJ0dsPR5y00HNJrdxwZ1d2ND8pjfaTenKF71hsBkULePjqxgqrsZqyNEu2e7ogM1giNqz",
            "width": 750,
          },
          {
            "height": 3024,
            "html_attributions":
              [
                '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104578111747260232633">Raymond LAM</a>',
              ],
            "photo_reference": "Aap_uEDZINRC-TvNlABT-VOU8Ae5iyofoml1D5woUCn-K1WT9O-_o-y-0cTNIJHhYv96aUEH8ZWRBO2b08ct1OBk9CbcKqL6A_Se9mcUNGG105gXGVb-qbCwLKUL4DCF-age8wMzJaUm3P_NE48WJJrLiWd19L2I3xAQUv--PL7jw4wXCZEa",
            "width": 4032,
          },
        ],
      "place_id": "ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4",
      "plus_code":
        {
          "compound_code": "45MW+C8 Pyrmont NSW, Australia",
          "global_code": "4RRH45MW+C8",
        },
      "rating": 4.1,
      "reference": "ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4",
      "reviews":
        [
          {
            "author_name": "Mark Smith (Mark ZZZ Smith)",
            "author_url": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/109015045837507592030/reviews",
            "language": "en",
            "profile_photo_url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gi-thk-CV41Ymw9Udvr0O5WL8Iguf9HYAKKyEWDxw=s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo",
            "rating": 5,
            "relative_time_description": "a year ago",
            "text": "Great place to visit, cafeteria great. Also has a good toilet.",
            "time": 1589072760,
          },
          {
            "author_name": "Agent Cliff (The Mediator)",
            "author_url": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/100253428394439543029/reviews",
            "language": "en",
            "profile_photo_url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhSLTmC1QVzI8oXWkDvqv_fTq1Xmm7_gM2udfRlbw=s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba3",
            "rating": 4,
            "relative_time_description": "5 months ago",
            "text": "Had an office tour here a few years ago and absolutely loved the look of it , as an AV person I was very impressed with the meeting rooms and loved the themes. Most of the staff were generally friendly and I was offered a range of different waters when waiting at reception.\n\nThe office is beautifully designed, onsite chef cooked a pretty alright lunch, staff interviewing as well were quite friendly and knew to be precise for technical interviews. I’d like to come back again one day for another tour just to see how it’s all going :)",
            "time": 1614291725,
          },
          {
            "author_name": "Xavier Le Baron",
            "author_url": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/104602961630797902494/reviews",
            "language": "en",
            "profile_photo_url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhbuCpv4_XNH8EWPZoGFwgWjiCQvCcVYiwJNxnMIPs=s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba4",
            "rating": 5,
            "relative_time_description": "3 months ago",
            "text": "Possibly the best office in Sydney? :)\nWhat an amazing place to work at!",
            "time": 1618388082,
          },
          {
            "author_name": "Binod Mainali",
            "author_url": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/110005203185645729740/reviews",
            "language": "en",
            "profile_photo_url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GitXX8rr6uxnCeLo4Kwd_UKm7ctfOYH9r7tcocqeg=s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo",
            "rating": 1,
            "relative_time_description": "6 months ago",
            "text": "I had some problem with google account, there is no way to contact google customer service. The only people i can contact to is the google ad Team. Google only cares about its ad what a selfish tech. There is not even a live chat, my password linked with google is compromised but there is no one to talk to. the 1800 no is a useless no or even the no provided at this store is useless. Google support only asks to send a feedback of the problem and nothing else. I had sent it but its been more than a month no one has contacted still. Such a selfish, greedy billionaire tech giant. Cant believe, even a small struggling business has someone to chat to. Such a low pathetic moral of google . Humanity will not be too long if our biggest tech are surround by just greed of $$$$$$....Shame on you # greedygoogle#greedysundarpichai#Australiagoogletaxloot.",
            "time": 1611295578,
          },
          {
            "author_name": "doug cliff",
            "author_url": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/114222669528052367599/reviews",
            "language": "en",
            "profile_photo_url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gjbd1ELb3S4E0R10kvV2h9EtBuME8xb9yWbtXa3qyU=s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba6",
            "rating": 4,
            "relative_time_description": "7 months ago",
            "text": "It appears from reading the reviews that Google in not too good at talking to people on the phone. I guess when you are as big as they are they can do what they want as there is not really another alternative. I use their services such as maps and mail but also contribute a lot of data such as photo’s and reviews. I was under the impression that what I was doing was helping others in the community. I had not realised that google could pick and choose who used these services and can block out any one out they don’t like. I was very upset when they black baned some Chinese manufactures who are making really good products. I had also not realised that Google is a slave to any crazy president that gets into power. Anyway I will keep using  their products as they are good and hope that one day they will be available for all to use.",
            "time": 1608012004,
          },
        ],
      "types": ["point_of_interest", "establishment"],
      "url": "https://maps.google.com/?cid=10281119596374313554",
      "user_ratings_total": 932,
      "utc_offset": 600,
      "vicinity": "48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont",
      "website": "http://google.com/",
    },
  "status": "OK",
}
```

Comment: your answer is helpful can I get this info by just giving postcode and country in endpoint?

Comment: I doubt it, how many restaurants could be returned in one call to a postcode. Imagine new york city. You'd have 10000 results for one postcode.